# unable to custome branding for eclipse 4 APP

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

With A eclipse 4 application, I have a branding problem; maybe it sounds very simple, but trust me, it have blocked me for days, and I still unable to solve it.

the problem is I want to put our own icon in the upper-left corner of the APP, but I can't make it work. I searched the web, and the answer I got is to set windowImages with the icons when defining the product(like following snippet of codes), what I already did, but it didn't work.

```
      <property
           name="windowImages"
           value="icons/sample2.gif,icons/ico32.gif,icons/ico48.gif,icons/ico64.gif">
     </property>
```

I tried this windowImages with a simple RCP, not a eclipse 4 application, it did work.

I know little about the difference between RCP and e4 application, but for me, it seems the biggest difference here is e4 will use org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application to load Application.e4xmi file;

besides trying windowImages, I also tried to set icon uri of the trimmed window in Application.e4xmi file, it didn't work either.

Please help me out of this. this feature is very simple, but without it, our APP should be seems too unprofessional.

Comment: I tried with a uguly way, that just call shell.setImage(xxx) in the code directly, anyway it works after all.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Bug in E4AP, which has now been resolved: [Bug 280825](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=280825), so now you can define your icon in the Application.e4xmi file.

If you want to have multiple Icons in different sizes, you need to directly use the JFace Window API to do so.

```
Window.setDefaultImages(new Image[] { //add your images here });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue , and finally i solved it by define the Icon URL for each window . Check below[image: Eclipse RCP 4]